# how to use while loop whilst checking items in a list

Tags: python

I'm trying to make my code so that only 7 items are entered and when 7 are entered then the loop will finish. But the following code does not do this at the moment.

Here is my code:

```
def occupants():
    oc = [0]*8
    while len(oc) <= 7:
        x = int(input("Enter a number"))
        oc.append(x)
        if len(oc) == 8:
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

Start with an empty list. Otherwise the loop body will not be run because there are already 8 elements.

```
oc = []

while len(oc) < 7:  # `<=` -> `<`
    x = int(input("Enter a number"))
    oc.append(x)
```

And, the condition should be adjusted. Otherwise, it will get one more item (8).

Answer (score 1):

You want an empty list, so that you will append something in every iteration, and after 7 iteration you want to break the loop. Pretty simple.

Now, let's see your attept.

```
>>oc = [0]*8
>>oc
[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
>>len(oc)
>>8
```

So, you are basically creating a list of 8 element each of which is 0 with the line `[0]*8`

```
while len(oc) <= 7: #This will never be true because len(oc) is 8 already.
```

So, take an empty list `[]`. Below code will work.

```
def occupants():
    oc = []
    while len(oc) < 7:
        x = int(input("Enter a number"))
        oc.append(x)
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason your code is not working is because you start with a list which already contains more than 7 items, so the `while` loop will finish before it starts. Secondly, the `break` condition is unnecessary as the `while` loop will end before it is `True`.

Unless the use case is more complex than the example given in the question, a simple list comprehension can achieve this result:

```
oc = [int(input("Enter a number")) for x in xrange(7)]
```

This runs for exactly 7 inputs, requires only a single line of code and is in my opinion much clearer and pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

**You Just need to recheck your logic anyways you can write you code like below**

```
def occupants():
  oc = []
  while len(oc) < 7:
    x = int(input("Enter a number"))
    oc.append(x)
  print oc
```

> You loop will run until the length of "oc" is 6 and at "len(oc)=6" it
>   will enter the loop to append the 7th element, and when the "len(oc)=7"
>   it won't enter the loop.